# Uncaught TypeError: Function is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I am getting `Fib.inputValidate is not a function`

I am wanting to run the `inputValidate` method so that on `keyup` the input validates both as an `integer` and as a `Fibonacci` number:

HTML looks like this:

```
<form id="fibonacci-form" action="" method="post">
  <input id="fibonacci" type="text" name="fibonacci"/>
</form>
```

Javascript ES6:

```
class Fibonacci {

  constructor() {
    const isPerfectSquare = '';
    const isFibonacci = '';
    const isInt = '';
    const inputValidate = '';
    this.isPerfectSquare = isPerfectSquare;
    this.isFibonacci = isFibonacci;
    this.isInt = isInt;
    this.inputValidate = inputValidate;
  } // constructor

  inputValidate(valueParsed, isInt) {
    var field = document.getElementById('fibonacci');
    var valueParsed = parseInt(field.value);
    field.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
      if (this.isInt(valueParsed) === false && field.value !== '') { 
        alert('Please enter a valid integer.'); 
      } 

      if(this.isFibonacci(valueParsed)) {
        alert(valueParsed + ' is a Fibonacci Number.');  
      } else {
        alert(valueParsed + ' is not a Fibonacci Number.'); 
      }
    });
  }

  isInt(valueParsed) {
    var field = document.getElementById('fibonacci');
    var valueParsed = parseInt(field.value);
    return !isNaN(valueParsed) && valueParsed == valueParsed.toFixed();
  }

  isPerfectSquare(valueParsed) { 
    var field = document.getElementById('fibonacci');
    var valueParsed = parseInt(field.value);
    var squaredValue = parseInt(Math.sqrt(valueParsed).toFixed(0));
    if (field.value !== '') { 
      return (squaredValue * squaredValue == valueParsed); 
    }
  } 

  isFibonacci(valueParsed) {
    var field = document.getElementById('fibonacci');
    var valueParsed = parseInt(field.value);
    var squaredValue = parseInt(Math.sqrt(valueParsed).toFixed(0)); 
      return this.isPerfectSquare(5 * valueParsed * valueParsed + 4) || this.isPerfectSquare(5 * valueParsed * valueParsed - 4); 
  } 
} // class

let Fib = new Fibonacci();
console.log(Fib.inputValidate());
```

Comment: Just remove all the `this.[function] = [function]` from the constructor.

Comment: I just did this, but then on `keyup` I get `this.isInt` is not a function.

Comment: Your constructor is overwriting all its functions with an empty string.

Comment: @RobMyrick that's a different [**problem**](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+this+event+listener+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The real problem** is that the `this` inside event handlers is not what you think it is. The `this` inside the event handler will be the (DOM) element that fired the event, not the instance of your class.

Now while you were trying to fix the real problem, you ended up with **another problem**, which is that you are shadowing the class methods with properties that have as values the empty string `''`.

To fix this, just remove the constructor all together as it doesn't do anything, and fix the issue with the `this` inside the event listener. To do that you have plenty of ways:

1. Use a variable outside the event listener scope called, for example, `that`, assign `this` to it and use `that` instead of `this` inside the event listener.

Like so:

```
var that = this;
field.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    // use 'that' instead of 'this'
    if(that.isInt(valueParsed) ...
});
```

2. Use an arrow function because arrow functions use their surrounding `this` value:

Like so:

```
// notice the arrow function passed to addEventListener
field.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    // you can now use 'this' here with no problems
    if(this.isInt(valueParsed) ...
});
```

1. `bind` your event handler to the instance of your class. `bind`ing a function will create a new function that always have its `this` value set to whatever you set it to.

Like so:

```
field.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    // you can now use 'this' here with no problems
    if(this.isInt(valueParsed) ...
}.bind(this)); // bind the function to its surronding 'this' value so 'this' inside it will be the same as 'this' outside it
```

**Working code:** Using an arrow function

```js
class Fibonacci {
  inputValidate(valueParsed, isInt) {
    var field = document.getElementById('fibonacci');
    var valueParsed = parseInt(field.value);
    field.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
      if (this.isInt(valueParsed) === false && field.value !== '') {
        alert('Please enter a valid integer.');
      }

      if (this.isFibonacci(valueParsed)) {
        alert(valueParsed + ' is a Fibonacci Number.');
      } else {
        alert(valueParsed + ' is not a Fibonacci Number.');
      }
    });
  }

  isInt(valueParsed) {
    var field = document.getElementById('fibonacci');
    var valueParsed = parseInt(field.value);
    return !isNaN(valueParsed) && valueParsed == valueParsed.toFixed();
  }

  isPerfectSquare(valueParsed) {
    var field = document.getElementById('fibonacci');
    var valueParsed = parseInt(field.value);
    var squaredValue = parseInt(Math.sqrt(valueParsed).toFixed(0));
    if (field.value !== '') {
      return (squaredValue * squaredValue == valueParsed);
    }
  }

  isFibonacci(valueParsed) {
    var field = document.getElementById('fibonacci');
    var valueParsed = parseInt(field.value);
    var squaredValue = parseInt(Math.sqrt(valueParsed).toFixed(0));
    return this.isPerfectSquare(5 * valueParsed * valueParsed + 4) || this.isPerfectSquare(5 * valueParsed * valueParsed - 4);
  }
} // class

let Fib = new Fibonacci();
```

```html
<form id="fibonacci-form" action="" method="post">
  <input id="fibonacci" type="text" name="fibonacci" />
</form>
```

**Enhanced working code:**

There still are some issues with your code that are related to the functionality rather than errors:

1. You declare functions as having arguments but you are not using them. For instance, the `valueParsed` argument is not used at all by even though it is an argument in all functions, instead you are fetching it from the DOM element every time. Use the argument.
2. The `valueParsed` (now used as argument) will be initialized inside `inputValidate`. It should be fetched from within the event listener not from outside it (every time the event fires we should get a new value for `valueParsed`).
3. For validation use `Number` instead of `parseInt` if you want to exclude float numbers (using `parseInt` will let float numbers pass validation as it takes only the integer bit from them). Also if validation fail, `return` to stop further code from executing. It (validation) still not very good though, I'll leave that to you.
4. **Suggestion:** You may want to use a button and listen for clicks on it instead of listening for `keydown` input on the field which is annoying. Create a button, and when the user clicks the button then check if the number they entered in the field is a Fibbonacci one or not. You would only change a line or two of code to achieve that.

```js
class Fibonacci {
  inputValidate() {
    var field = document.getElementById('fibonacci');

    field.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
      var valueParsed = Number(field.value);
      if (this.isInt(valueParsed) === false) {
        alert('Please enter a valid integer.');
        return;
      }

      if (this.isFibonacci(valueParsed)) {
        alert(valueParsed + ' is a Fibonacci Number.');
      } else {
        alert(valueParsed + ' is not a Fibonacci Number.');
      }
    });
  }

  isInt(valueParsed) {
    return !isNaN(valueParsed) && valueParsed == valueParsed.toFixed();
  }

  isPerfectSquare(valueParsed) {
    var squaredValue = parseInt(Math.sqrt(valueParsed).toFixed(0));

    return (squaredValue * squaredValue == valueParsed);
  }

  isFibonacci(valueParsed) {
    var squaredValue = parseInt(Math.sqrt(valueParsed).toFixed(0));
    return this.isPerfectSquare(5 * valueParsed * valueParsed + 4) || this.isPerfectSquare(5 * valueParsed * valueParsed - 4);
  }
} // class

let Fib = new Fibonacci();
```

```html
<form id="fibonacci-form" action="" method="post">
  <input id="fibonacci" type="text" name="fibonacci" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove (or empty) your constructor. Class methods are inherited by instances of the class automatically, and as it is your constructor is simply overriding them with properties whose values are empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `this.inputValidate` and `const inputValidate` from your constructor. And write your method this way...

```
inputValidate = (valueParsed, isInt) => {
 // do stuff here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Your constructor is overwriting every single function in your class. Here's what actually happens to each method (I'm using `isInt()` as an example, but it's exactly the same for each one):

You set `isInt` to `''` (empty string) in the constructor:

```
const isInt = '';
```

Then, you create a property named `isInt`, and set it to `isInt` the string:

```
this.isInt = isInt;
```

So `isInt` ends up being an empty string. Here's a minified example:

```js
class Fibonacci {

  constructor() {
    const isInt = '';
    this.isInt = isInt;
  } // constructor

  isInt(valueParsed) {
    var field = document.getElementById('fibonacci');
    var valueParsed = parseInt(field.value);
    return !isNaN(valueParsed) && valueParsed == valueParsed.toFixed();
  }
} // class

let Fib = new Fibonacci();
console.log(Fib);
```

As you can see, the property `isInt` is equal to `""` (empty string), which is why you can't call it like a function - it's a string.

## Solution

Place the function declarations within the constructor:

```js
class Fibonacci {

  constructor() {
    this.inputValidate = function(valueParsed, isInt) {
      var field = document.getElementById('fibonacci');
      var valueParsed = parseInt(field.value);
      field.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        if (this.isInt(valueParsed) === false && field.value !== '') {
          alert('Please enter a valid integer.');
        }

        if (this.isFibonacci(valueParsed)) {
          alert(valueParsed + ' is a Fibonacci Number.');
        } else {
          alert(valueParsed + ' is not a Fibonacci Number.');
        }
      });
    }

    this.isInt = function(valueParsed) {
      var field = document.getElementById('fibonacci');
      var valueParsed = parseInt(field.value);
      return !isNaN(valueParsed) && valueParsed == valueParsed.toFixed();
    }

    this.isPerfectSquare = function(valueParsed) {
      var field = document.getElementById('fibonacci');
      var valueParsed = parseInt(field.value);
      var squaredValue = parseInt(Math.sqrt(valueParsed).toFixed(0));
      if (field.value !== '') {
        return (squaredValue * squaredValue == valueParsed);
      }
    }

    this.isFibonacci = function(valueParsed) {
      var field = document.getElementById('fibonacci');
      var valueParsed = parseInt(field.value);
      var squaredValue = parseInt(Math.sqrt(valueParsed).toFixed(0));
      return this.isPerfectSquare(5 * valueParsed * valueParsed + 4) || this.isPerfectSquare(5 * valueParsed * valueParsed - 4);
    }
  }
} // class

let Fib = new Fibonacci();
console.log(Fib);
```

Comment: Why would you move all the methods into the constructor. OP doesn't need that, he just needs to fix the issue with the `inputValidate` function (`this` not being the instance of the class), which lead him to override the methods in the constructor. You didn't fix that, so basically you've just made the code even worse.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. Are you suggesting removing all of the `const` lines, or something else?

Comment: No. What I'm saying is that you moved the methods into the constructor which is not a good idea as they should be outside of it like OP already have. OP's problem is that inside `inputValidate` he set an event listener and uses `this` inside that event handler. Since `this` inside the event handler is the element and not the instance, the code doesn't work. OP tried to fix that by assigning the methods into variables in the constructor, that didn't work, OP then tried to assign variables to the methods inside the constructor, that didn't work neither.

Comment: How do I know this? OP did post another question earlier which he's deleted.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that - I looked for other questions, but I have < 10k, so I couldn't see that one.

Answer (score 0):

Problem raised for below lines in your code.

> const inputValidate = '';
>
> this.inputValidate = inputValidate;

what does it mean, it means const variable **inputValidate** assigned to
**this.inputValidate**, So **this.inputValidate** is not a function.

In contrast function **inputValidate(valueParsed, isInt)** added into prototype of the created object for the class by nature.

So, when you called below lines

```
let Fib = new Fibonacci(); 
console.log(Fib.inputValidate());
```

then find **Fib.inputValidate** in the class/constructor functions first, if not found then find **Fib.inputValidate** in prototype.

so, when you called **Fib.inputValidate()** then it finds the function in its constructor function, but it founds **Fib.inputValidate** is a property like variable but not function.

Thats why showing **Uncaught TypeError: Function is not a function**

For clear conception you can read the article [enter link description here](https://medium.com/@robertgrosse/how-es6-classes-really-work-and-how-to-build-your-own-fd6085eb326a)

Actually there is no class in javascript but ES6 introduce a class keyword, Actually this class keyword simply syntactic sugar.

So everyone should keep in mind actual scenario of Class.

***Finally some modification of your code:***

```
constructor() {
    const isPerfectSquare = '';
    const isFibonacci = '';
    const isInt = '';
    const inputValidate = '';
  } // constructor
```

Now Fib.inputValidate() will be reachable.

And finally into the keypress/keyup or any other event **this** always point the Dom element so if you use **arrow function** for keypress/keyup or any other event then **this** will point the class object.